Nature of objects and their location in space
Suppose we know that there is a pointlike object moving around in space. We want to know or measure it's location, so we attempt to find the object. This is done my looking around. We get a point coordinate as a result of our observation. So location of an object is a result of measurement.
Now suppose someone predict the position of that point object and say it is at point O. Is this a valid statement because position is a result of observation?
Or can we even say that an object occupy a "point" or set of "points" when we don't see it, just think about the object?
Thus an object is an identity which gives the value of a "point" or "set of points" (extended objects) when position is measured.

You might want to edit the question in an explanatory fashion to stave off closure.

Firstly, you need to distinguish classical from quantum objects, since the latter don't always have clear-cut locations.
Sticking with classical objects, you will confuse yourself if you consider that the location of an object is a result of observation. It is better to think that your knowledge of the location is the result of observation. It's a bit like any other kind of measurement. If you get on a scale it will tell you your weight, but your weight is not created by the scale, or attributed to you by the scale- you had a weight before you got on the scale, and the scale simply put a value to it.
On that basis, it does make sense to consider a classical object as having a position regardless of whether or not you have pinned it down through observation. The assumption is that it always has a position- but you just don't know where it is. Of course, that assumes the object itself is reasonably well defined. Vague objects, such as a mist, are a different case.
Quantum objects are not thought to have clear-cut positions. Generally speaking, a quantum object has a probability of being detected at any place, the probability being determined by something called the 'wave function' associated with particle. Except when the particle is detected at a particular place, the particle doesn't have to have a well defined position.
Of course, some head scratching arises when you consider that a classical object is actually a collection of quantum objects, so why do we think classical objects have well-defined positions when their constituent quantum particles don't? The answer is that it's an approximation. In reality the positions of classical objects are slightly fuzzy, but if the degree of uncertainty is tiny compared with the object itself, then we can assume it is zero for most practical purposes.

For a classical object, the position is the place the object occupies whether you look at it or not. For quantum objects, it's the place where a detection event occurs.

Sorry I deleted the comment just now

Though this question is likely to be closed, on my reading, this is quite a sophisticated question, and that sophistication may escape notice.
You ask:

Now suppose someone predict the position of that point object and say it is at point O. Is this a valid statement because position is a result of observation

So, the short answer is, it depends on the goal of the statement. According to Wittgenstein, language production always entails a language-game. You have rightfully sussed out that the language or description of location itself is normative. Any measurement imposes a logic and convention onto external reality. Thus, the choice to orient north upwards on a map, for instance, is a convention, not strictly speaking a brute fact about the northern hemisphere. That's because the making of the map requires decisions be made about abstraction and language. The same can be said of selecting a spatiotemporal origin, which is often done for a particular type of utility, and is not inherent to space itself.
In the philosophy of science, this hidden subjectivity embedded in the language of description of observation is called theory ladenness. From WP:

In the philosophy of science, observations are said to be "theory-laden" when they are affected by the theoretical presuppositions held by the investigator. The thesis of theory-ladenness is most strongly associated with the late 1950s and early 1960s work of Norwood Russell Hanson, Thomas Kuhn, and Paul Feyerabend, and was probably first put forth (at least implicitly) by Pierre Duhem about 50 years earlier.

So, the statement is true within the context of the convention (the theoretical presuppositions) in which it is uttered according to the goals of those who utter. In this way, predictions are only as adequate as the models they are made from, and building a model depends on the purpose for having the model. None of that is a claim about space itself. Such a co-mingling of objectivity and subjectivity shows that Hume's thoughts on Ought-Is are adequate, but not without limits. Consider Searle's work on Deriving "Ought" From "Is". All measurements, including the location of things in space as descriptions, are based on these sorts of implicit preferences and conventions.

In regards to, does an object occupy a point or a locus of points, it depends on the model or abstraction of the language that expresses the abstraction. In Netwonian diagrams, we often represent objects as point-forces, for instance, but in full-blown relativity, we might use something more sophisticated like tensor space to describe the same object.
